# image full width on column with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the image on the left to be with no padding or margin as the photo below in the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pq7cxg8e/4/

```
<div class="box-blanco">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2 hidden-xs">
<a href="salas-estudios/caravaca-ds55">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1" alt="Caravaca" width="85" height="68"></a>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
<span class="text-muted visible-xs pull" style="color: #A6A6A6; font-size: 12px;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i>Chacarita</span>
<h5><a href="salas-estudios/caravaca-ds55" class="text-inverse" style="color: #6C6C6C; font-weight:400;">Test Title</a></h5>
<div class="col-separador-s"></div>
<p class="text-muted" style="font-size: 12px;">
<span class="text-muted hidden-xs" style="color: #A6A6A6;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i>Chacarita</span>&nbsp;
<span class="text-muted" style="color: #A6A6A6;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i>4000-8531</span>&nbsp;
<span class="text-muted" style="color: #A6A6A6;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-mobile fa-lg"></i>15-4000-7713</span></p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```html
padding: 10px!important;
```

Causes the image to be padded, if you want to size the div to a particular size then do that. Otherwise keep padding @ 0.

Changing the image size will also change the size of the box.
As you can see in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gcampton/do34opoo/1/

Comment: regardless of the image size is it possible to keep the box proportions and full sized in the column where it is?

Comment: You mean you want the image overflow:hidden regardless of image size?

Comment: You need to revise your question because "I want the image on the left to be with no padding or margin as (*like) the photo below" was answered. To answer your question: yes if you just set width/height you should be able to keep it, the images will get cropped though if they don't fit the div.